# Obtaining unique values from a list

Tags: java

I know there are classes like Hashset that can remove duplicates but I'm not sure if I can apply it to my case.
I have a list of dates, separated into month and day respectively.

```
private static List<MonthDay> Dates() {
    List<MonthDay> dates = new ArrayList <MonthDay>();
    dates.add(MonthDay.of(JAN, 1));
    dates.add(MonthDay.of(JAN, 2));
    dates.add(MonthDay.of(FEB, 3));
    dates.add(MonthDay.of(MAR, 1)); 
    return dates;
}
```

I've also created a method to return lists of specified dates.

```
private static List<MonthDay> Month(Month month) {
    List<MonthDay> monthList = new ArrayList<>();
     for (MonthDay m : Dates()) {
        if (m.getMonth().equals(month)) {
            monthList.add(m);
         }
    }
    return monthList;
}
```

Now, I want to have a method to check whether my month is unique or not (i.e., if there is only one date that falls in that month), and then return a list of the dates containing the unique months.

e.g. FEB and MAR are unique months in the list, so the output I should get is

> [--02-03, --03-01]

How do I go about doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `HashMap` to keep track of how many times each `Month` appears in your `dates` list.

Create a Map variable:

```
Map<Month, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<Month, Integer>();
```

Itterate through your list. If the map already contains the key, get the value associated with the date key, add one and put the key with the new value back into the Map:

```
for (MonthDay md : dates){
    Month currentMonth = md.getMonth();
    if(myMap.containsKey(currentMonth)){
        myMap.put(currentMonth, myMap.get(currentMonth) + 1);
    }
    else{
        myMap.put(currentMonth, 1);
    }
}
```

Then to check which months are unique, iterate through your list of dates. For each date, check the corresponding Month number in the map. If the number is 1, the month of that date is unique!

```
List<MonthDay> uniqueDates = new ArrayList<MonthDay>();
for (MonthDay md : dates) {
    if(myMap.get(md.getMonth()) == 1){
        uniqueDates.add(md);
    }
}

return uniqueDates;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`MultiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) which is, essentially, a `Map` from a key to a collection of values.

So you can find unique months by going over all the keys and checking if they only have one value associated (this wouldn't be too expensive since you only have 12 months). Then you can merge all the lists with one value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to inherit ArrayList and overrding add() method.

```
public class MonthDayList extends ArrayList{
  public void add(MonthDay e){
      if(!contains(e)) super.add(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Think does not answer the question.  You need to be surer than that.

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8, you can do groupings using streams to find what Months are unique.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<MonthDay> dates = Dates();

    // Group by Months
    Map<Month,List<MonthDay>> groups = dates.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(date -> date.getMonth()));

    // Filter to unique months
    List<List<MonthDay>> uniqueMonths = groups.values().stream()
            .filter(list -> list.size() == 1).collect(Collectors.toList());

    // Display results
    System.out.println(uniqueMonths);
}

private static List<MonthDay> Dates() {
    List<MonthDay> dates = new ArrayList();
    dates.add(MonthDay.of(Month.JANUARY, 1));
    dates.add(MonthDay.of(Month.JANUARY, 2));
    dates.add(MonthDay.of(Month.FEBRUARY, 3));
    dates.add(MonthDay.of(Month.MARCH, 1));
    dates.add(MonthDay.of(Month.JULY, 1));
    dates.add(MonthDay.of(Month.DECEMBER, 20));
    dates.add(MonthDay.of(Month.DECEMBER, 21));
    return dates;
}
```

Results:

```
[[--07-01], [--03-01], [--02-03]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the MultiMap/HashMap approach, but here is another that I came up with for this use case.

change your MonthDay object to (Month,Int) (if you haven't already) where the Month is an Enum defined as the following.

```
enum Month {
   JAN,FEB,MAR,APR,MAY,JUN,JUL,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC
    }
```

Then make an array `int[] monthsCounter = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];` wherever it is you decide to do the adding of input dates to your arraylist.

Then using a [switch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statement update the monthsCounter as you traverse the dates arraylist. (to be clear, this would be after you create the dates arraylist).

```
// Switch on the enum value.
switch (Month) {
case JAN:
    monthsCounter[0]++;
    return;
case FEB:
    monthsCounter[1]++;
    return;
case MAR:
    monthsCounter[2]++;
    return;
 .....
case DEC:
    monthsCounter[11]++;
    return;
}
```

When you finish going through the arraylist of dates, all you would need to do is iterate through `monthsCounter` checking to see which index has a value of 1. Then use that index to determine the month to lookup the date in the `Month` method for your outputs.

```
for(int i =0; i < monthsCounter.length; i++){
    if(monthsCounter[i] == 1) {
        int tempMonth = i;
        Month(getMonthFromInt(tempMonth)); //create method to return Month from input Int arg.
        //the list returned ^ will give date that you can either store or print
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice and simple (though inefficient) method is to just stream the list filtering for dates whose month appears only once in the list:

```
dates().stream().filter(d1 -> 
    dates().stream().filter(d2 -> d1.getMonth().equals(d2.getMonth()))
        .count() == 1)
    ...
```